# Android gallery view keeps crashing and scrolls really slowly. What's wrong with my code

Tags: android, android-imageview, baseadapter, android-gallery, listadapter

Basically I have a simple gallery view that scrolls through a list of Images however when I run the program on my Samsung galaxy s3 mini (Not an emulator) It scrolls through the images so slowly when i swipe and has a lot of lag. Also it crashes after I scroll for a couple of seconds. What am I doing wrong??? I eventually want to implement this into another app with a lot more images and a lot more scrolling. This should work since I'm using my phone and not an emulator so it shouldn't be a performance problem. It's in the code. In my logcat it says "Fatal signal 11" Can someone please help. Here is my code.

THE LIST ADAPTER:

```
package com.example.nowlpractice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
private Context mContext;

private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,
        R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,
        R.drawable.koala,
};

public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 
{
    mContext = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


// Override this method according to your need
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[index]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));

    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    return i;
}
}
```

THE ACTIVITY:

```
package com.example.nowlpractice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NwActivity extends Activity 
{

 ImageView selectedImage;  
 private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.koala,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic4,
    };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nw);

         Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    selectedImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    gallery.setSpacing(1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));

     // clicklistener for Gallery
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(NwActivity.this, "Your selected position = " + position,           
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // show the selected Image
            selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        }
    });
}
}
```

AND THE XML:

```
<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

HERE IS MY LOGCAT

```
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at   
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at   
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at 
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at a
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at   
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at j   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
07-17 12:24:11.360: I/dalvikvm(13610):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native    
Method)
07-17 12:24:11.360: A/libc(13610): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1),    
thread     
13610 (le.nowlpractice)
```

Comment: can you please post stack trace of exception? By the way Gallery is deprecated, it's better to use ViewPager instead of it

Comment: @Chaosit Would a ViewPager work the same as a gallery though??? and i posted my logcat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'r logcat look like a OutOfMemory

just some questions : 
What is the size of you'r picture ?

Have you try not with imageView but with TextView?..(just for test)

What is you'r version on the galaxy s3 mini?

and for sure, try a viewpager even if the function is similar...

Answer (score 0):

replace this constructor

```
mContext = context;
   TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 

create like this resource 

 <resources>
     <declare-styleable name="Gallery1">
      <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground"></attr>
    </declare-styleable>
  </resources>
```